# Chain CollectionChanged Events

Tags: events, event-handling, system.reactive, observablecollection, reactive-programming

I'm trying to see how it would be possible to chain together x number of  ObservableCollections.CollectionChanged event, exposed as a N level depth object tree to a single parent level CollectionChanged event that consumers can listen to?  Essentially I want to funnel or bubble all child CollectionChanged events up to the top most parent.  A number of solution I've noticed that tackle similar issues make an assumption of a fixed number of levels, say 2 deep. I idea is to support any level of depth.

Originally I had hoped I could just pass the instance of the FieldInfos to the child constructors and attach directly to the handler. However i get an error stating the "Event 'CollectionChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of+= or -=.

Thanks,

```
public class FieldInfos
    {
        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

        private ObservableCollection<Field> _fields;

        public ObservableCollection<Field> Fields => _fields ?? (_fields = new ObservableCollection<Field>());
    }



    public class Field
    {
        public string Name;

        private ObservableCollection<FieldInstance> _instances;
        public ObservableCollection<FieldInstance> Instances => _instances ?? (_instances = new ObservableCollection<FieldInstance>());
    }

    public class FieldInstance
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You would need to modify `ObservableCollection<>` to make this work. Otherwise you could create a facade pattern to do it - effectively you would create you're own `NestedObservableCollection<>` class that wraps an internal `ObservableCollection<>`.

Comment: Would you mind providing some sample code that illustrates what your proposing as a possible solution?

Comment: @Mike did you try it out?

Comment: Indeed marked as solution.

Comment: Um, Mike, you didn't mark it as the solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is subclass the original `ObservableCollection<T>`.

You'd need at least one interface to avoid covariance problems. You can also have your own classes to implement the `INotifyDescendantsChanged` interface.

```
public interface INotifyDescendantsChanged
{
    event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler DescendantsChanged;
}

public class ObservableBubbleCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, INotifyDescendantsChanged
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler DescendantsChanged;
    protected virtual void OnDescendantsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler = DescendantsChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(sender, e);
    }

    private readonly Func<T, INotifyDescendantsChanged> childSelector;
    public ObservableBubbleCollection() { }
    public ObservableBubbleCollection(Func<T, INotifyDescendantsChanged> childSelector)
    {
        this.childSelector = childSelector;
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        OnDescendantsChanged(this, e);

        if (childSelector == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems.Cast<T>())
                childSelector(item).DescendantsChanged += OnDescendantsChanged;

        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (var item in e.OldItems.Cast<T>())
                childSelector(item).DescendantsChanged -= OnDescendantsChanged;
    }
}
```

To use it, replace instances of `ObservableCollection` and pass a selector to the collection.

```
public class FieldInfos
{
    private ObservableBubbleCollection<Field> _fields;

    public ObservableBubbleCollection<Field> Fields => _fields ?? (_fields = new ObservableBubbleCollection<Field>(fi => fi.Instances));
}

public class Field
{
    public string Name;

    private ObservableBubbleCollection<FieldInstance> _instances;
    public ObservableBubbleCollection<FieldInstance> Instances => _instances ?? (_instances = new ObservableBubbleCollection<FieldInstance>());
}

public class FieldInstance
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fi = new FieldInfos();
        fi.Fields.DescendantsChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Change from {0}", sender.GetType());
        };

        var field = new Field();
        fi.Fields.Add(field);

        field.Instances.Add(new FieldInstance());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Asti, this is awesome. Very complete code sample you've provided to illustrate the solution. Really appreciate you taking the time to provide this for me and anyone coming by in the future.  Spot on!

Comment: @Mike You're very welcome, Mike. Just passing on some of that Christmas spirit! :)